# Snapshot API for ERC20 or ERC721

Tags: erc-20, erc-721, snapshot, api

I'm looking for an API that allows to export all wallets from a given ERC20 Token or ERC721 NFT. I already tried some, but most of them take multiple minutes to respond, which is too slow for us, as we want to integrate it on the frontend. Any API out there? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome Ptr43!

I think you could try Radiant Segment (https://segment.radiant.so), you can find their API docs here: https://docs.radiant.so

Comment: This is super cool, Ethereum & Polygon as of now, hope they add support for additional chains :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use The Graph/Moralis/Covalent if the smart contract emits events.

Comment: Thanks, do you maybe have a link to Graph?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the NFT owners by contract address using Moralis [getNFTOwners](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/reference/get-nft-owners).

Here is a step-by-step example of how to do it: https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/how-to-get-nft-owners-by-an-address

Let me know if you need any help!

Disclosure: I work at Moralis

Comment: Looks nice for NFTs, would be great to have ERC20 owners as well.